# Would it be possible to replace the atmega328p on the Arduino Nano with an atmega324p?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, atmega328p

I have an atmega324p and was wondering if I could attach it to my Arduino nano by removing its atmega328p. If I cannot due to pin layout, would it be possible to make my own PCB of an Arduino nano with for the pin layout of the atmega324p?

Comment: yes and yes ... almost anything is possible

Comment: So can I use an Arduino nano schematic with more connector pins then since there are more digital/analog pins?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but it requires you to do some research. You would want to check if there is an Arduino core library for the mega324. Then you need to find out how the core library maps the pins then layout your board based on that. Maybe someone has done this already?

Comment: if you consider that the arduino is open hardware and you can get cad files on the net i wonder why you are asking here, if it was me i already have try it.